# Jquery suddenly unable to drill into json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a weird scinario. I have been using $.ajax() to make ajax calls to my server for data and have been using the same sort of format for these server calls. All has been going fine but suddenly I wrote a function and returned a JSON object that jQuery is unable to drill into. I looked at it in Firebug and everything appears normal. Can someone help me here to understand why suddenly I am unable to drill into this particular data object?

Here is the ajax code:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "php/getoptions.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'id='+id,
        success: function(j)
        {           
            alert(j.isdefault); 
        }
    });
```

when I try to do this, the alert gives me "undefined." I have tried "alert(JSON.stringify(j))" and I see the valid json being returned. I have even taken the json that I saw in Firebug and run it through JSONLint and it returned valid.

Here is a sample of the json coming back:

```
[{"isdefault":"1","option1":"1","option2":"0","option3":"0","option4":"1","option5":"1"}]
```

WHAT IS GOING ON? Why can jQuery suddenly not drill into this data set?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need...

```
alert(j[0].isdefault);
```

...because the object that has the `isdefault` property is at index `0` of an Array.

Comment: Thanks that did it. But I why did that matter all of a sudden? I never had these kinds of issues with other json arrays returned from PHP....odd

Comment: As he says. Your JSON contains an object wrapped in an array (notice the square brackets around the whole thing). You'd do well to start using `console.dir` or `console.log` for debugging instead of `alert` - much more versatile, and gives you much more useful output. Also, not as annoying. With that, you could use `console.dir(j)` and discover that you have your JSON received and properly parsed, and that it is an array (which does not contain a property named `isdefault`).

Comment: @ackerchez: Nothing would have changed with jQuery. Something must have changed with your server response, or maybe you're doing something else different. Can't say for sure.

Comment: yea, i am aware of console debugging I just dont have access to those logs without having to bug a server admin for them so I just use alert instead.

Comment: @ackerchez: I think Amadan meant the browser console, but it seems that you already use that, since you mentioned `Firebug`.